# How to add more layers to Convolutional Neural Network text classification TensorFlow example?

Tags: tensorflow

According to the documentation, the model presented in [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification_character_cnn.py) is similar to the following paper:
"[Character-level Convolutional Networks for Text Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01626)"

I found that the original model (presented in the paper) contains 9 layers deep with 6 convolutional layers and 3 fully-connected layers, but the implemented example contains only two convolutional layers:

```
with tf.variable_scope('CNN_Layer1'):
    # Apply Convolution filtering on input sequence.
    conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(
                 byte_list, N_FILTERS, FILTER_SHAPE1, padding='VALID')
    # Add a RELU for non linearity.
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
    # Max pooling across output of Convolution+Relu.
    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(
            conv1,
            ksize=[1, POOLING_WINDOW, 1, 1],
            strides=[1, POOLING_STRIDE, 1, 1],
            padding='SAME')
    # Transpose matrix so that n_filters from convolution becomes width.
    pool1 = tf.transpose(pool1, [0, 1, 3, 2])
with tf.variable_scope('CNN_Layer2'):
    # Second level of convolution filtering.
    conv2 = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(
                 pool1, N_FILTERS, FILTER_SHAPE2, padding='VALID')
    # Max across each filter to get useful features for classification.
    pool2 = tf.squeeze(tf.reduce_max(conv2, 1), squeeze_dims=[1])
```

If anybody can help me to extend this model for more layers?

Answer (score 0):

1. Similar to BVLC Caffenet :

   def bvlc_caffenet(imgs,weights,biases):
      # mean subtraction
      mean = tf.constant([123.68, 116.779, 103.939], dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 1, 1, 3], name='img_mean')
      images = imgs-mean

   #conv1
      conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(images,weights['c1'], [1, 3, 3, 1], padding='VALID')
      out1  = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, biases['b1']))
      pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(out1,ksize=[1,3,3,1], strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID')

   #conv2
      conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1,weights['c2'], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
      out2  = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv2, biases['b2']))
      pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(out2,ksize=[1,3,3,1], strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID')

   #conv3
      conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool2,weights['c3'], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
      out3  = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv3, biases['b3']))

   #conv4
      conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d(out3,weights['c4'], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
      out4  = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv4, biases['b4']))

   #conv5
      conv5 = tf.nn.conv2d(out4,weights['c5'], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
      out5  = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv5, biases['b5']))
      pool5 = tf.nn.max_pool(out5,ksize=[1,3,3,1], strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID')

   #flattening
      shape = int(np.prod(pool5.get_shape()[1:]))
      pool5_flat = tf.reshape(pool5, [-1, shape])

   #fc6
      fc6  = tf.matmul(pool5_flat,weights['f6'])
      out6 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(fc6,biases['b6']))
      out6 = tf.nn.dropout(out6,0.5)

   #fc7
      fc7  = tf.matmul(out6,weights['f7'])
      out7 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(fc7,biases['b7']))
      out7 = tf.nn.dropout(out7,0.5)

   #fc8
      fc8  = tf.matmul(out7,weights['f8'])
      out8 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(fc8,biases['b8']))
      out8 = tf.nn.dropout(out8,0.5)

   probs = tf.nn.softmax(out8)
      return probs

   ## Initialized Weights and Biases for the Network

   weights = {
   'c1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7,7,3,96],stddev=0.1)),
   'c2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5,5,96,256],stddev=0.1)),
   'c3': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,256,384],stddev=0.1)),
   'c4': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,384,384],stddev=0.1)),
   'c5': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,384,256],stddev=0.1)),
   'f6': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4096,2048],stddev=0.1)),
   'f7': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2048,2048],stddev=0.1)),
   'f8': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2048,1000],stddev=0.1))
   }
   biases = {
   'b1' : tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[96])),
   'b2' : tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[256])),
   'b3' : tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[384])),
   'b4' : tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[384])),
   'b5' : tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[256])),
   'b6' : tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[2048])),
   'b7' : tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[2048])),
   'b8' : tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1000]))
   }

Or

2. follow this (another format) : https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frossard/vgg16/vgg16.py

Are these helpful ?